# Save data in android fragment

Tags: android-fragments, xamarin, mvvmcross, savestate

I am developing **Xamarin Android Application**.I don't know how to save variable value which I have in myfragment.I want that variable's value back when I reopen my application after completely closing it.How can I implement it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guys I have already solve this using below code in fragment:

```
protected void saveset(){
        var prefs =this.Activity.GetSharedPreferences("MyApp",FileCreationMode.Private);
        var prefEditor = prefs.Edit();
        prefEditor.PutString ("LoginUserName",LoginUserName.Text.Trim());
        prefEditor.PutString ("ProfilePicture",ImageUrl);
        prefEditor.PutString ("UserID", User_Id);
        prefEditor.Commit();
    }
protected void retrieveset(){
        //retreive 
        var prefs =this.Activity.GetSharedPreferences("MyApp", FileCreationMode.Private);            
        LoginUserName.Text= prefs.GetString ("LoginUserName", string.Empty);
        ImageUrl= prefs.GetString ("ProfilePicture", string.Empty);
        User_Id = prefs.GetString ("UserID", string.Empty);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use SharedPreferences (ISharedPreferences in Xamarin):

```
ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences (mContext);
ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefs.Edit ();
editor.PutString ("your_string_key", "your_string_value");
editor.Apply();
```

You can offcourse save other types of data as well

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that I use, I save the value in my shared preferences (SettingsPreferences) in a property in my view model:

```
SpinnerItem _selectedNumberPlayers;
public SpinnerItem SelectedNumberPlayers
{
    get { return _selectedNumberPlayers; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedNumberPlayers != value)
        {
            _selectedNumberPlayers = value;

            SettingsPreferences.SelectedNumberPlayers = _selectedNumberPlayers.Index;

            FireMyPlayersChanged(AppSection.Settings);

            RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedNumberPlayers);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my SettingsPreferences.SelectedNumberPlayers:

```
public static int SelectedNumberPlayers
{
    get 
    { 
        return Settings.AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault(StringConstants.SelectedNumberPlayers, SelectedNumberPlayersDefault); 
    }

    set
    {
        Settings.AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue(StringConstants.SelectedNumberPlayers, value); 
    }
}
```

Where Settings.AppSettings is CrossSettings.Current from the XAM Settings nuget package.

To read your variable back when your app starts, simply do something like this:

```
var myVar = SettingsPreferences.SelectedNumberPlayers;
```